# data.symbol not holding value

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, discord.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to take the data stored in symbol and have puppeteer type it into a search bar using `scrapePage.type`. I am not receiving any error messages but the code is acting as if data.symbol is not holding any value even though it is because when it sends the embed message, the .addField for symbol use `data.symbol` to send the message.

```js
try { // Alpha AI Scrape
    scrapePage.goto('https://app.flowalgo.com/');
    await scrapePage.waitForSelector('#alphaAI-v1', {timeout: 10000});
    await scrapePage.addScriptTag({url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js'});


    let data = await scrapePage.evaluate((darkFlowData) => {
        let $ = window.$;
        let data = [];

        // Scrape Ratings
        $('#fa_aai > div.alpha-ai-signals.animated.fadeIn').each(function() {
            let symbol = $('div:nth-child(1) > div.symbol > span').text().trim();

            ticker = symbol;

            if (darkFlowData.lastAlphaAIIDs.includes(symbol)) return;


            let date = $('div:nth-child(1) > div.date > span').text().trim();
            let reference = $('div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3)').text().trim();
            let signal = $('div:nth-child(1) > div.sentiment').text().trim();


            data.push({symbol, date, reference, signal});

        }); // Scrape Ratings



        return data;
    }, darkFlowData);



    await scrapePage.waitForSelector('#filter-flow > div > input[type=text]', {timeout: 10000});
    await scrapePage.addScriptTag({url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js'});
    await scrapePage.type('#filter-flow > div > input[type=text]', data.symbol);



    let data1 = await scrapePage.evaluate((darkFlowData) =>{
        let $ =window.$;
        let data1 = [];

        //Scrape for Contracts
        $('#optionflow > div.component-body.ps.ps--theme_default.ps--active-y > div.data-body > div:nth-child(20)').each(function() {
            let symbol1 = $('#optionflow > div.component-body.ps.ps--theme_default.ps--active-y > div.data-body > div:nth-child(20) > div.ticker > span').text().trim();

            if (darkFlowData.lastAlphaAIIDs.includes(symbol1)) return;

            let exp = $('#optionflow > div.component-body.ps.ps--theme_default.ps--active-y > div.data-body > div:nth-child(20) > div.expiry > span').text().trim();
            let strike = $('#optionflow > div.component-body.ps.ps--theme_default.ps--active-y > div.data-body > div:nth-child(20) > div.strike > span').text().trim();
            let type = $('#optionflow > div.component-body.ps.ps--theme_default.ps--active-y > div.data-body > div:nth-child(20) > div.contract-type > span').text().trim();

            data1.push({symbol1, exp, strike, type});
        });

        return data1;
    }, darkFlowData);



    for (let entry of data) { // Output Ratings
        darkFlowData.lastAlphaAIIDs.push(entry.symbol);
        if (darkFlowData.lastAlphaAIIDs.length > 500) darkFlowData.lastAlphaAIIDs.shift();

        let color = config.colors.aai;


        let embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setColor(color)
            .setTitle('Alpha AI Alert')
            .addField('Symbol', entry.symbol, true)
            .addField('Contract Selection', entry.symbol)
            .addField('Expiration', entry.exp)
            .addField('Strike', entry.strike)
            .addField('Type', entry.type)
            .setTimestamp()



        for (let guild of clientGuilds) {
            if (typeof darkFlowData.guilds[guild.id].channels.alphaAI !== 'undefined') {
                client.channels.get(darkFlowData.guilds[guild.id].channels.alphaAI).send(embed);
            }
        }

        sendDMAlerts(entry.symbol.toLowerCase(), embed, null, 'alphaAI');
    }

    fs.writeFile(config.files.darkFlow, JSON.stringify(darkFlowData), err => {});
} catch (error) {
    console.log('ALPHA AI SCRAPE ERROR: ' + error);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an array of objects. When you use each object in a loop like in `for (let entry of data) { ... addField('Contract Selection', entry.symbol)`, the `symbol` is there. But `data` array has no `.symbol` property outside of a loop, it is `undefined`. It has to be something like `data[0].symbol`.